Varnish. Fails to use, send or receive the correct Hostname, therefore wrong content served
I hope i can get some assistance in resolving this issue with varnish:
I have the following configuration:
Configuration Overview:

HTTP Traffic:    
Apache listens on port 8080.
Varnish listens on port 80 and forwards requests to Apache on port 8080.

HTTPS Traffic:
Apache handles SSL termination directly on port 443.
Varnish listens on port 80 for HTTP requests.

Adminpanel: Virtualmin 7 GPL
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Apache is configured correctly, it serves the correct website as per DocumentRoot in the apache conf file for the VirtualHost/DomainName
As soon as i install varnish, then a problem arises. The DocumentRoot becomes /var/www/html, as if apache/varnish is not recognizing the virtualhost or can't match the hostname, and therefore a alternative DocumentRoot is used(/var/www/html). I can't wrap my head around why this is happening. I have double checked the apache configuration and all is configured correctly.
The DocumentRoot should be: /home/dewebshop/magento2/pub , as it is configured in the apache conf files. And It works properly from apache, but not from Varnish then it uses /var/www/html
I tried adding the following code to the /etc/varnish/default.vcl file, but that did not solve the problem.:
sub vcl_recv {
        
  if (req.http.host) {
        set req.http.Host = req.http.host;
    }
}

As a consequence of the wrong DocumentRoot used(/var/www/html), the health check generates a backend error because the file returns a 404.
 .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }

I tried replacing the /etc/varnish/default.vcl with a very basic version, but the wrong DocumentRoot is still used, that implies that the problem might not be in this vcl file.
/etc/varnish/default.vcl
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
#        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
          -a :80 \
          -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
          -p feature=+http2 \
          -p http_resp_hdr_len=64k \
          -p http_resp_size=128k \
          -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
          -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/varnishreload

I set apache to listen to port 8080
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
Listen 8080
Listen 443

Here is the relevant apache virtualhost lines for the host:
<VirtualHost 149.210.243.33:8080 [2a01:7c8:aabb:70:5054:ff:fe36:327f]:8080>
 DocumentRoot /home/dewebshop/magento2/pub
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 149.210.243.33:443 [2a01:7c8:aabb:70:5054:ff:fe36:327f]:443>
DocumentRoot /home/dewebshop/magento2/pub

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Forward requests to Varnish
# Forward requests to Varnish
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
</VirtualHost>

Here is apachectl -S
root@ubuntu:~$ sudo apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
[2a01:7c8:aabb:70:5054:ff:fe36:327f]:8080 dewebshop.online (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dewebshop.online.conf:1)
[2a01:7c8:aabb:70:5054:ff:fe36:327f]:443 dewebshop.online (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dewebshop.online.conf:51)
149.210.243.33:8080    dewebshop.online (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dewebshop.online.conf:1)
149.210.243.33:443     dewebshop.online (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dewebshop.online.conf:51)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex fcgid-pipe: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-proctbl: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33

This is the /etc/varnish/default.vcl (Created by magento admin panel)
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
#        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {

        #added because magento sucks
#  if (req.http.host) {
#        set req.http.Host = req.http.host;
#    }



    if (req.restarts > 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass customer, shopping cart, checkout
    if (req.url ~ "/customer" || req.url ~ "/checkout") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(health_check.php)$") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # Bypass authenticated GraphQL requests without a X-Magento-Cache-Id
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if ((req.url !~ "/graphql" || !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }


    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);

        # When the frontend stops sending the auth token, make sure users stop getting results cached for logged-in users
        if (req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
            hash_data("Authorized");
        }
    }

    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }

    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s that are not marked as private
    if ((beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) || beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        # Collapse beresp.http.set-cookie in order to merge multiple set-cookie headers
        # Although it is not recommended to collapse set-cookie header,
        # it is safe to do it here as the set-cookie header is removed below
        std.collect(beresp.http.set-cookie);
        # Do not cache the response under current cache key (hash),
        # if the response has X-Magento-Vary but the request does not.
        if ((bereq.url !~ "/graphql" || !bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id)
         && bereq.http.cookie !~ "X-Magento-Vary="
         && beresp.http.set-cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
           set beresp.ttl = 0s;
           set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        }
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

    # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
    if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
        beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
        beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    # If the cache key in the Magento response doesn't match the one that was sent in the request, don't cache under the request's key
    if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.uncacheable) {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "UNCACHEABLE";
    } else if (obj.hits) {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    if (!resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}

The request does pass through varnish:
sudo varnishlog
*   << Request  >> 18
-   Begin          req 17 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1724754038.213498 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1724754038.213498 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 57130 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: dewebshop.online
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
-   ReqHeader      Dnt: 1
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: private_content_version=5bbc2e20c413c9fb6072b732fb16c494; lang=en; s_fid=406394D596AD0356-05F76B80A46CF07E; s_cc=true; redirect=1; testing=1; sid=c60abda9a8bdc8b9730fa90cedae6544; form_key=pNkAyrsXTQKRwQmt; apt.uid=AP-XD7ZED5OKDHG-2-1-17245986379
-   ReqHeader      Priority: u=0, i
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 87.210.82.16
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: dewebshop.online
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Server: dewebshop.online
-   ReqHeader      Connection: Keep-Alive
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 87.210.82.16
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 87.210.82.16, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Hit            3 -1597.631370 259200.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     restart
-   Timestamp      Restart: 1724754038.213624 0.000125 0.000125
-   Link           req 19 restart
-   End

*   << BeReq    >> 20
-   Begin          bereq 19 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1724754038.213698 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: dewebshop.online
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
-   BereqHeader    Dnt: 1
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: private_content_version=5bbc2e20c413c9fb6072b732fb16c494; lang=en; s_fid=406394D596AD0356-05F76B80A46CF07E; s_cc=true; redirect=1; testing=1; sid=c60abda9a8bdc8b9730fa90cedae6544; form_key=pNkAyrsXTQKRwQmt; apt.uid=AP-XD7ZED5OKDHG-2-1-17245986379
-   BereqHeader    Priority: u=0, i
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: dewebshop.online
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Server: dewebshop.online
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 87.210.82.16, 127.0.0.1
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    grace: none
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 20
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1724754038.213723 0.000024 0.000024
-   Timestamp      Connected: 1724754038.213793 0.000094 0.000069
-   BackendOpen    29 default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 42864 connect
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1724754038.213859 0.000160 0.000066
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1724754038.214681 0.000982 0.000821
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2024 10:20:38 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache
-   BerespHeader   Upgrade: h2,h2c
-   BerespHeader   Connection: Upgrade
-   BerespHeader   Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Aug 2024 22:31:01 GMT
-   BerespHeader   ETag: "29b0-6209dae040bba-gzip"
-   BerespHeader   Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 3121
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html
-   TTL            RFC 120 10 0 1724754038 1724754038 1724754038 0 0 cacheable
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1724754038 cacheable
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1724754038.214747 0.001048 0.000066
-   Filters         gunzip esi_gzip
-   BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespUnset    Content-Length: 3121
-   BerespUnset    ETag: "29b0-6209dae040bba-gzip"
-   BerespHeader   ETag: W/"29b0-6209dae040bba-gzip"
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   Fetch_Body     3 length -
-   Gzip           G F E 10672 3138 80 25024 25034
-   Gzip           U F - 3121 10672 80 80 24903
-   BackendClose   29 default recycle
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1724754038.215567 0.001868 0.000820
-   Length         3138
-   BereqAcct      1935 0 1935 305 3121 3426
-   End

*   << Request  >> 19
-   Begin          req 18 restart
-   Timestamp      Start: 1724754038.213624 0.000125 0.000000
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 57130 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: dewebshop.online
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not)A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="127", "Chromium";v="127"
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
-   ReqHeader      Dnt: 1
[cut off becau8se max 40.000 chars per post]

To recap: The problem is:
Apache is running a virtualdomain from /home/dewebshop/magento2/pub
As soon as i install and configure varnish, the document served comes from /var/www/html
I am tempted to make a symbolic link for /var/www/html to /homr/dewebshop/magento2/pub but i think there must be someone wiser than me with a better solution ;)

I see that your Varnish backend is proxying to 127.0.0.1, whereas the relevant virtual hosts are listening in IP 149.210.243.33.
There are 2 potential solutions:

Set your backend .host property to 149.210.243.33.
Let your Apache virtual hosts listen for every IP address so requests on 127.0.0.1 match those virtual hosts.

